# changing API data

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing an e-commerce flutter app,as you know in this kind of apps we have categories, I have an endpoint to get product categories,
the problem is that I get data like this

[

'GIFT',
'HOME_AND_LIVING',
'WEDDING_AND_PARTY',
'CLOETHES_AND_SHOES',

]

but I need to use it like this

[

'Gift',
'Home & Living',
'Wedding & Party',
'Cloethes and Shoes'

]

so I need to change each string.
any idea?

Comment: Is the data an array or an object? You've used curly braces `{` `}` instead of square brackets `[` `]` and it's just not clear if that was your intention

Comment: sorry, my bad. it's inside [].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can easily achieve this with these steps:

```dart
void main() {
  List<String> oldWords = [
    'GIFT',
    'HOME_AND_LIVING',
    'WEDDING_AND_PARTY',
    'CLOETHES_AND_SHOES',
  ];

  List<String> newWords = [];

  for (var word in oldWords) {
    newWords
        .add(word.replaceAll("_", " ").replaceAll("AND", "&").toLowerCase());
  }
  print(newWords);
}
```

Comment: what if I want the first letter of the word to be capital?

Comment: I have a set of `string_extensions` https://pub.dev/packages/string_extensions , you can use the `.toTitleCase()` method at the end, after `.toLowerCase()` and you are good to go.

Comment: You can in fact just use the `.toTitleCase()` instead of `.toLowerCase()`.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to do this. Basically, you are starting with:

```
List<String> data = [
    'GIFT',
    'HOME_AND_LIVING',
    'WEDDING_AND_PARTY',
    'CLOETHES_AND_SHOES',
];
```

If you just want the first character of each phrase to be capitalized, you could do this:

```
List<String> transformed = data.map((s) {
    var chars = s.split('');
    return "${chars[0].toUpperCase()}${s.substring(1).toLowerCase()}";
}).toList();
```

and the result will be:

```
[Gift, Home_and_living, Wedding_and_party, Cloethes_and_shoes]
```

Lets say you want the same result, but without the `_`. Then you could do this:

```
List<String> transformed2 = data.map((s) {
    var chars = s.split('');
    return "${chars[0].toUpperCase()}${s.substring(1).replaceAll("_", " ").toLowerCase()}";
}).toList();
```

and the result will be:

```
[Gift, Home and living, Wedding and party, Cloethes and shoes]
```

Now let's say you want to capitalize each word in the phrase and remove `_`. You could do this:

```
List<String> transformed3 = data.map((s) {
    String _s = s.replaceAll("_", " ");
    var words = _s.split(' ');
    List<String> parts = words.map((s) {
        var chars = s.split('');
        return "${chars[0].toUpperCase()}${s.substring(1).toLowerCase()}";
    }).toList();
    return parts.join(" ");
}).toList();
```

and the result will be:

```
[Gift, Home And Living, Wedding And Party, Cloethes And Shoes]
```

Finally, you could clean this up by looking for specific words that you don't want capitalized. In this case, the word `"and"`. So if you do this:

```
List<String> transformed4 = data.map((s) {
    String _s = s.replaceAll("_", " ");
    var words = _s.split(' ');
    List<String> parts = words.map((s) {
        var chars = s.split('');
        return "${chars[0].toUpperCase()}${s.substring(1).toLowerCase()}".replaceAll("And", "and");
    }).toList();
    return parts.join(" ");
}).toList();
```

you will be this result:

```
[Gift, Home and Living, Wedding and Party, Cloethes and Shoes]
```